# Finding a zero of a linear function inside a convex set

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose I am given a linear function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ and a non-empty convex set $K$ which is given as the intersection of half planes. Is there any standard easy method for finding a solution to $F(x)=0$ with $x\in K$?

What I am looking for is a fast and as simple as possible algorithm. Some possibilities that I see would be

1. Some kind of gradient descent with $\|F(x)\|^2$ as loss function, but this is probably overkill.
2. Finding the subspace $\ker F$, starting with a point in there, and then iteratively move to the correct side of each of the hyperplanes delimiting $K$.
3. Start with a point in $X:=K\cap\{F(x)_i\ge0\ \forall i\}$ (need to find one first!), and then do gradient descent in $X$ with loss function $L:=\sum_iF(x)_i$, noticing that the gradient of L is constant, so when we meet one of the hyperplanes delimiting $X$ we simply project the gradient and follow the resulting vector.

Does any of these methods work well? Is there another, even better method? Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Pick fast, or simple. Not both :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially "phase 1" of linear programming (finding a basic feasible solution).  The half-planes to intersect correspond to inequality constraints, the function $F$ to equality constraints.